# SSRS returns #Error for any expression on the server while in designer everything is working

Tags: reporting-services

I have a few simple reports with few column width expressions. Somehow all the expressions stop working and return #Error. Even very simple expressions like `=Fields!Count.Value + 1` when run on the server returns #Error while it is working in Preview in VS. While `=Fields!Count.Value` returns value on both server and VS Preview.

[image]

How do I get a meaningful message on why this #Error occurs?

Comment: In the example above is the first column =Fields!Count.value and the second column =Fields!Count.value + 1? What if you include =CINT(Fields!Count.value) + 1?

Comment: Yes - you are right. I've tried =CINT(Fields!Count.value) + 1 and =CINT(Fields!Count.value) both return #Error. I've setup SSRS on another PC and test this report - it works fine. So the issue with SSRS or Server configuration.

Comment: Very odd! Have you tried adding this calculation via the Dataset as a calculated field rather than calculating it as an expression? Also, are there any differences between the rdl on the PC where it doesn't work and the version where it does work. Sometimes oddities can get stuck in the rdl!

Comment: Try adding a Filter on the dataset to check your data. `=IIF(ISNUMERIC(Fields!Count.Value), 1, 0)`. Set the TYPE to INTEGER , = , and 1 for the value. If you don't get an error after this, then you have data that isn't numeric.

Comment: ISNUMERIC also return #error. I've found same issue with reports that wasn't change and was workig fine before. Also as all these reports are working on another PC with SSRS I don't think that the issue with report or expression.